# Is there a way to remove Chrome history without deleting omnibox records?

Tags: google-chrome, crash, osx-mavericks

My Google Chrome keeps crashing randomly and I have tried everything. Im on Mavericks. I removed and added back my user, I uninstalled and reinstalled chrome, I disabled all my extensions, but nothing helped.

But I’m guessing maybe its my browsing history that’s too heavy. Because I’ve been working with chrome for years and never deleted my browsing history. I want to remove my browsing history but I don’t want to lose Omnibox suggestions.

Is there a way for this? I just need the omnibox to still suggest URL’s.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and there isn’t a way. OS X 10.9.1 solved the Chrome Crash problem though.